# Change colour of ggplot interactively with plotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

I have the following example data:

```
d <- data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10),
                pheno1 = c(rep("a", 5), rep("b", 5)),
                pheno2 = c(rep("d", 3), rep("e", 3), rep("f", 4)))
p <- ggplot(d, aes(x=x, y=y, colour = pheno1)) +
     geom_point()
ggplotly(p)
```

Now I'm looking for a way to change the coluring scheme from `pheno1` to `pheno2` interactively in `plotly`.

I know that I can change the colour scheme with

```
list(method = "restyle",
     args = list("colorscale", "..."),
     label = "...")
```

But I havent found anything to change the data underlying the colouring.